# Duda sobre mas de una condición en estructura condicional while

Tags: c++, loops, while, operadores

Buen día, soy nueva en el mundo de la programación y trato de crear un programa en c++ que funcione mientras la variable de repetición no sea mayor a cinco y el numero ingresado no sea múltiplo de cinco y que al final imprima los números ingresados; sin embargo no logro hacer que la segunda condición se cumpla. El código es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int re=0,suma=0;
    int num[5]={1,1,1,1,1};

    for (int p=0;p<5;p++)
    {
        num[p]=-1;
    }

    while (re<5&&num[re]%5!=0)
    {
        cout<<"Introduce un numero entero"<<endl;
        cin>>num[re];
        suma=suma+num[re];
        cout<<"El resultado de su suma hasta el momento es "<<suma<<endl;
        re++;
    }

    cout<<"El ciclo termino"<<endl;
    cout<<"La suma total es "<<suma<<endl;

    for(int re=0;re<5;re++)
    {
        cout<<"Numero en posicion "<<re<<" es "<<num[re]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Espero haber sido clara en cuanto a mi problema. Acepto sugerencias de cualquier tipo en cuanto a mi forma de programar. 
¡Saludos!

Comment: solo como depuración, podrias intentar hacer un cout de num[re]%5 luego de pedir el numero? con eso te sacas la duda de si da 0 o no.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás comprobando la condición antes de haber leído los datos:

```
while (re<5&&num[re]%5!=0)
```

En ese código dices: "*Mientras `re` sea menor que `5` y el valor de `num` en la posición `re` no contenga un número cuyo residuo al dividirlo por `5` sea `0`, continúa*".

El problema es que cuando pasas por esa condición `re` siempre tiene el valor de la iteración anterior y `num[re]` siempre contiene `1`. Suponiendo que entro los números `2`, `3`, `5`, `5` y `5` vamos a verlo paso por paso:

```
| paso            | re | num         | num[re] |
+-----------------+----+-------------+---------+
| inicio          | 0  | {1,1,1,1,1} | 1       |
| 1ª comprovacion | 0  | {1,1,1,1,1} | 1       |
| 1ª lectura      | 0  | {2,1,1,1,1} | 2       |
| 2ª comprovacion | 1  | {2,1,1,1,1} | 1       |
| 2ª lectura      | 1  | {2,3,1,1,1} | 3       |
| 3ª comprovacion | 2  | {2,3,1,1,1} | 1       |
| 3ª lectura      | 2  | {2,3,5,1,1} | 5       |
| 4ª comprovacion | 3  | {2,3,5,1,1} | 1       |
| 4ª lectura      | 3  | {2,3,5,5,1} | 5       |
| 5ª comprovacion | 4  | {2,3,5,5,1} | 1       |
| 5ª lectura      | 4  | {2,3,5,5,5} | 5       |
```

Si no quieres que tu comprovación vaya un paso por detrás de tu inserción de datos, deberías cambiar la condición a `do`-`while`:

```
do
{
    cout<<"Introduce un numero entero"<<endl;
    cin>>num[re];
    suma=suma+num[re];
    cout<<"El resultado de su suma hasta el momento es "<<suma<<endl;
    re++;
}
while ((re < 5) && ((num[re - 1] % 5) != 0));
```

Haciendo la comprobación **después** de leer los datos te aseguras de estar comprobando el dato que toca, fíjate que además a `re` le resto `1` para indizar `num` porque si no estaría mirando la posición de la siguiente vuelta.

Answer (score 5):

**Editado**
Hay que pedir el valor de num[re] antes de hacer la validación en el while, se puede de esta manera o como en la respuesta de Marco

```
//..código...
for (int p=0;p<5;p++)
{
    num[p]=-1;
}

cout<<"Introduce un numero entero"<<endl;
cin>>num[re];
while (re<5&&num[re]%5!=0)
{
cout<<num[re]%5;
    suma=suma+num[re];
    cout<<"El resultado de su suma hasta el momento es "<<suma<<endl;
    re++;
    cout<<"Introduce un numero entero"<<endl;
    cin>>num[re];
}
 //...código...
```

Comment: El ejemplo de lo que le está pasando está en el código de ella, por otra parte, no sé aún si lo que escribí, responde a su pregunta, por lo tanto no podría colocar cómo "arreglarlo", sin embargó agregaré un poco de código!

Comment: Así quedó un poco mejor?

Comment: La respuesta a mi entender no cumple los requerimientos de la pregunta. Si tenemos la entrada [1, 3, 15] el ciclo seguirá su ejecución a pesar de que 15 es múltiplo de 5. Esto debido a que re sigue siendo menor que 5

Comment: Tienes razón, la ajustaré.

Answer (score 5):

Creo que el error está en la lógica que estás empleando y específicamente en la posición del incremento que haces en el contador `re`.

Me explico. En forma de psudocódigo podemos ver que tu programa hace lo siguiente:

1. Inicializa `num` a **-1**
2. Mientras el total de números introducidos sea menor a 5 Y Mientras el número introducido no sea múltiplo de 5 entonces:

   - Obtener valor introducido por el usuario
   - Suma valor introducido a acumulador
   - Imprimir suma
   - Incrementa contador de números introducidos.

El problema que veo es en la condición "Mientras el número introducido no sea múltiplo de 5" porque con la instrucción

```
num[re]%5!=0
```

estás apuntando al índice inadecuado. Es decir, debido a que ya incrementaste el valor en

```
re++;
```

en la lectura que haces en la condición de terminación del bucle estás apuntando al índice siguiente al recién introducido por el usuario. Deberás hacer lo siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int re=-1,suma=0;
    int num[5]={1,1,1,1,1};

    for (int p=0;p<5;p++)
    {
        num[p]=-1;
    }

    while (re<5&&num[re]%5!=0)
    {
        re++;
        cout<<"Introduce un numero entero"<<endl;
        cin>>num[re];
        suma=suma+num[re];
        cout<<"El resultado de su suma hasta el momento es "<<suma<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"El ciclo termino"<<endl;
    cout<<"La suma total es "<<suma<<endl;

    for(int re=0;re<5;re++)
    {
        cout<<"Numero en posicion "<<re<<" es "<<num[re]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Notarás el cambio en el valor de inicialización de la variable `re` y el cambio de posición el incremento a la misma variable.

Encontrarás la salida de dicho programa [aquí](https://onlinegdb.com/B1AdzltRb)

Saludos!